# How to calculate the same index in dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

This is my code example:

```
budi = {"Name" : "Budi", "Gender" : "Male", "Age" : 18}
ahmad = {"Name" : "Ahmad", "Gender" : "Male", "Age" : 7}
ika = {"Name" : "Ika", "Gender" : "Female", "Age" : 18}

marged = [budi, ahmad, ika]
```

I want to keep the results show the same value or index, for example:

```
male : 2
```

Comment: Please don't attach images of text. Just paste the text into your question instead.

Comment: Okay, i'll edit it

Comment: That's not a code example, it's some sample data and a statement of what you want it to look like after processing. Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: @SiHa I've never done it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider you have a list of records.
What you want is to count the records which "Gender" is "Male".

You can do that with a small function:

```
budi = {"Name" : "Budi", "Gender" : "Male", "Age" : 18}
ahmad = {"Name" : "Ahmad", "Gender" : "Male", "Age" : 7}
ika = {"Name" : "Ika", "Gender" : "Female", "Age" : 18}

merged = [budi, ahmad, ika]

def count_items(records, key, value):
    values = [r[key] for r in records if key in r]
    return values.count(value)
```

Example:

```
print(count_items(merged, "Gender", "Male"))
# -> 2

print(count_items(merged, "Age", 7))
# -> 1
```

Of course, you can simplify:

```
males = [r["Gender"] for r in merged].count("Male")
```

Comment: Of course, the function is not necessary if you only have a single usage.

Comment: Is there a loop method for / while to do it?

Comment: Of course, you can use a for loop instead of a list comprehension, but is more verbose. See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) and a conditional comprehension:

```
num_males = sum(1 for subdict in marged if subdict['Gender'] == 'Male')
```

This iterates over all dictionaries in `marged` (shouldn't this be called `merged`?) and checks if the `'Gender'` is `'Male'`. You could also check for the number of people between age 5 and 10 this way:

```
num_age_5_to_10 = sum(1 for subdict in marged if 5 <= subdict["Age"] <= 10)
```

Of course you could also replace the `1` with the boolean condition (because `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` to `0`):

```
num_males = sum(subdict['Gender'] == 'Male' for subdict in marged)
num_age_5_to_10 = sum(5 <= subdict["Age"] <= 10 for subdict in marged)
```